# How to render a self closing tag using TagBuilder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

The following code:

```
var canonical = new TagBuilder("link");
canonical.MergeAttribute("rel", "canonical");
canonical.MergeAttribute("href", url);
return new MvcHtmlString(canonical.ToString());
```

Creates a tag:

```
<link href="http://local.domain.com/" rel="canonical"></link>
```

Is it possible to render

```
<link href="http://local.domain.com/" rel="canonical"/>
```

instead, using TagBuilder?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
canonical.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);
```

Comment: I actually didn't see there were that option in `ToString`. That worked, thank you.

Comment: @rock, I'm sure Bruno knows how to accept. ;)  And he has to wait a little bit before he's allowed to (since he just asked it).

Answer (score 3):

You can also try.

```
TagBuilder  tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("link");
tagBuilder.TagRenderMode = TagRenderMode.SelfClosing;
```

Comment: The TagRenderMode property seems to only be available on the Asp.Net core version of TagBuilder. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.tagbuilder.tagrendermode?view=aspnetcore-2.2